# React changing text of child on button hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the text of a child function component when I hover over a button of my parent class component. I'm having trouble accessing the prop though in the child component and getting null. Any help is appreciated

parent component:

```
export default class PathfindingVisualizer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            AlgoDef: null,
        };
    }

render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="button-bar">    //buttons that change state
                    <button 
                    onClick={() => this.helperDikjstras()}
                    onMouseOver={() => this.setState({ AlgoDef: "Dikj"})}
                    >Dikjstras</button>
                    
                    <button 
                    onClick={() => this.helperAstar()}
                    onMouseOver={() => this.setState({ AlgoDef: "Astar"})}
                    >A*</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <AlgoExplaination algoName={this.AlgoDef} />   //changes its text based on state of parent
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

my child component:

```
export default function AlgoExplaination(props) {
    const [text, setText] = useState("default");

    useEffect(() => {
        switch (props) {
            case "Dikj":
                setText("Dikjstra");
                break;
            case "Astar":
                setText("Astar");
                break;
            default:
                setText("useEff");
        }
        //console.log(`text: ${text}`);
        //console.log(props);
        // console.log(props.algoName);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

both console logging `props` gives me: `{algoName: null}`. and `props.algoName` gives me `null`

Comment: First `algoName={this.AlgoDef}` should be `algoName={this.state.AlgoDef}`. Second, `switch (props) {` should be `switch (props.AlgoDef) {`. Third, why do you have both class component and functional component with hooks? Please use 1 way

Comment: Thank you, if you want to put this as an answer id love to upvote you! I'm just learning react so I wanted to try both. Is there a reason I shouldn't be mixing them though?

Comment: I have added an answer but only to explain 3rd point as others have been covered in another answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh) has mentioned in a comment, you are passing props to your `AlgoExplaination` (sic) component **incorrectly** like this:

```
<AlgoExplaination algoName={this.AlgoDef} />
```

You intended to pass the `AlgoDef` property of your state, which is `this.state.AlgoDef`, so change accordingly to this:

```
<AlgoExplaination algoName={this.state.AlgoDef} />
```

Furthermore, when you access the `algoName` property of your props, you currently attempt to access it as if it were the props object itself **incorrectly** like this:

```
switch (props) {
```

The `props` object for `AlgoExplaination` will be an object with an `algoName` property that looks (partially) like this:

```
{ algoName: "Dikj" }
```

So, the value you need is actually stored in `props.algoName`. Therefore, please change accordingly to this:

```
switch (props.algoName) {
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@Wyck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563833/wyck) has addressed most of the points, I'll focus this answer on the last point:

> Third, why do you have both class component and functional component with hooks? Please use 1 way

#### Class vs Functional component

In theory, a class component has lifecycle events and state, where as a functional component is just a function that returns `JSX.Element`. Such components were called stateless.

Because of this, class component had a bit of overhead over functional component, and as a performant option functional component were preferred.

#### Hooks

Hooks are a way in react to give functional components access to have its own state and few major lifecycle events. This is achieved using closure (*not going in full depth*) and craftsmanship. This also makes class components obsolete as everything can be achieved in functional component.

#### Which one to use?

As a preference, its suggested to use functional component with hooks as they are easy to use and are performant as well, in comparison.

#### Why to use one?

In general programming practice, as a developer, you should use a single way to do things. Benefit of this is, it helps in fast reading.

If I use a `for` loop in one section and a `Array.forEach` in next, as a developer, I will be asked to read and understand the purpose. This adds overhead and reduces readability. Having same approach moves the focus of reader to just the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to destructuring the props, to be more clear.

In

```
export default function AlgoExplaination(props)
```

Can be something like:

```
export default function AlgoExplaination({algoName})
```

So you can use it in your switch statment.

```
switch (algoName) {
            case "Dikj":
                setText("Dikjstra");
```

Right now, you are passing all props but you will have to access as props.algoName in the switch statment.